# Python Tkinter instance has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

> AttributeError: MyGUI instance has no attribute 'tk'

Also, how do I make the created window have a fixed size and not be able to resize with the mouse? Or after changing label value by clicking on button.

My code:

```
from Tkinter import*

class MyGUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__mainWindow = Tk()    

    #lbl
        self.labelText = 'label message'
        self.depositLabel = Label(self.__mainWindow, text = self.labelText)

    #buttons
        self.hi_there = Button(self.__mainWindow)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello",
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.testeo

        self.QUIT = Button(self.__mainWindow)
        self.QUIT["text"] = "QUIT"
        self.QUIT["fg"]   = "red"
        self.QUIT["command"] =  self.quit

    #place on view
        self.depositLabel.pack()
        self.hi_there.pack() #placed in order!
        self.QUIT.pack()

    #What does it do?
        mainloop()

    def testeo(self):

        self.depositLabel['text'] = 'c2value'

        print "testeo"

    def depositCallBack(self,event):
        self.labelText = 'change the value'
        print(self.labelText)
        self.depositLabel['text'] = 'change the value'

myGUI = MyGUI()
```

What's wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should invoke the super constructor for `Frame`. Not sure, but I guess this will set the `tk` attribute that the `quit` command relies on. After that, there's no need to create your own `Tk()` instance.

```
def __init__(self):
    Frame.__init__(self)
    # self.__mainWindow = Tk()
```

Of course, you will also have to change the constructor calls for your widgets accordingly, e.g.,

```
self.hi_there = Button(self)  # self, not self.__mainWindow
```

or better (or at least shorter): set all the attributes directly in the constructors:

```
self.hi_there = Button(self, text="Hello", command=self.testeo)
```

Also add `self.pack()` to your constructor.

(Alternatively, you could change the quit command to `self.__mainWindow.quit`, but I think the above is better style for creating Frames, see e.g. [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/minimal-app.html).)

Answer (score 1):

This error typically means you are calling `SomeTKSuperClass.__init__` and forgetting the first parameter, which must be `self`. Remember that `__init__` is a *class* method (static function) in this context, not an *instance* method, which means that you must explicitly pass it `self`.